# PartialView convert from MVC to .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following MVC code:

```
**** Edit.cshtml
@Html.Action("_Customer", "Orders", new { idCustomer = @Model.idCliente })

**** Controller.cs
        public IActionResult _Customer(int idCustomer)
        {
            var model = new Customer();

            // Ricavo Dati
            Utente u = new Utente();
            model = u.aDettagliCustomer(idCustomer, conn);

            return PartialView(model);
        }

**** View _Customer.cshtml
@model Models.Customer

Ragione Sociale: @Model.RagioneSociale<br />
@Model.Nome @Model.Cognome<br />
@Model.Sesso<br />
@Model.Indirizzo<br />
@Model.CAP @Model.Citta (@Model.Provincia)<br />
@Model.Stato
Tel: @Model.Telefono<br />
Cod.Fiscale: @Model.CodiceFiscale<br />
P.IVA: @Model.PartitaIVA<br />
email: @Model.Email
```

I have read that it is advisable to use @await Html.PartialAsync, but how convert this code?

I Tried to convert the code with View Component.

But i get the error:
InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'CustomerViewComponent' could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.

The Code:

```
    public class CustomerViewComponent: ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ConnectionStrings> conn;

        public CustomerViewComponent(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> config)
        {
            this.conn = config;
        }


        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int idCustomer)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(idCustomer);
            return View("_Customer", items);
        }

        private Task<Customer> GetItemsAsync(int idCustomer)
        {
            var model = new Customer();

            // Ricavo Dati
            Utente u = new Utente();
            model = u.aDettagliCustomer(idCustomer, conn);

            return Task.FromResult<Customer>(model);
        }

    }
```

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CustomerViewComponent", new { idCustomer = @Model.idCliente })
```

Comment: Where did you read that from and were there any explanation why it is advisable? This might be a case where View Components would be usable instead of the partial view

Comment: OK, You can give me an example of how the following code should be converted to using View Components?

Comment: It should be `@await Component.InvokeAsync("Customer", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

use  `<partial name="partialName" model="ModelName" />` instead of returning partial view in controller.
you can use this n

Comment: how to add parameter   new { idCustomer = @Model.idCliente } to the tag <partial>?